# How do I change an image in rails using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an image tag for trump.gif in my view.

```
<%= image_tag("trump.gif", size: "800x800", id: "pic") %>
```

Now after a certain time I want to change the gif to a png in javascript.

So I have a script tag in which there is a setTimeout function that is changing the src attribute of the image tag. However, the image does not display. Looks like I messed up something in the path for the url.

```
<script>
 setTimeout(
 function(){ 
  // Replace the gif
 document.getElementById("pic").setAttribute('src', "/assets/trump_final.png");
 }, 5000);
</script>
```

The image however does not show. I think I m missing out on something with the src url .

Any help ?

Comment: If "trump.gif" is the original path, then shouldn't the other image be just "trump_final.png" without the "/assets/" prefix?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Here is my console error: (index):129 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: I think the issue has to do with the way I declared the id in the image_tag

Comment: Right, that means that your `.getElementById()` call is returning `null`

Comment: Yeah I  know . But why ? What is the way around what I am trying to do ?